# Why cant you curl into nano?

Tags: linux, curl, nano

So i was using the curl command the other day to get the information on a webpage and i piped it into nano to try and save the information but all it did was make the console completely unresponsive. The command i used was in the form:

```
curl -vk [web address] | nano
```

This caused the console to completely seize up, i sorted the issue by using a different command but i cant seem to find an answer anywhere on why this happens...

Can anyone enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

`nano` reads `stdin` with the dash `-` notation.

In your case, that'd give you :

```sh
curl -vk [web address] | nano -
```